# Is this a 16th type of a convex pentagon that can tile a plane?

Tags: geometry, tiling

As you can read here:
http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2015/08/14/432015615/with-discovery-3-scientists-chip-away-at-an-unsolvable-math-problem
there are now 15 known convex pentagons, or nonregular pentagons with the angles pointing outward, that can "tile the plane."

Recently I have stumbled upon this site:
http://domesticat.net/quilts/sunshine
(see the 2nd image from the top:)

[image: Hirschhorn tiling]

This tiling uses 60-160-80-100-140 pentagons, all boarders are equal in size. It has a Hirschhorn circle in the middle with 18 "arms" that are stretching outwards. Those arms get thicker by adding 2 pentagons with each level. The picture above shows the 2 and a half levels.

Here you can see a bathroom floor tiled with such pattern. It shows more levels, but not a full circle:
http://burtleburtle.net/bob/other/bathroom.html

[image: bathroom floor]

Question:
**How can it be proved that such a tiling covers the plane?**

Comment: The _tile_ itself here is not new -- it's a case of "type 1" in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) on pentagonal tilings because two of the sides are parallel. Therefore it does not count as a 16th type.

Comment: Specifically, it's the non-periodic tiling here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Nonperiodic_monohedral_pentagons_tilings